# STREAMLIT [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NAME.xlsx'

Tags: anaconda, conda, streamlit

I have this error :

**No such file or directory: 'Survey.xlsx'**

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px
from PIL import Image

st.set_page_config(page_title='Survey Results')
st.header('Survey Results 2021')
st.subheader('Was the tutorial helpful?')

### --- LOAD DATAFRAME
excel_file = 'Survey.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'DATA'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,
                   sheet_name=sheet_name,
                   usecols='B:D',
                   header=3)

df_participants = pd.read_excel(excel_file,
                                sheet_name= sheet_name,
                                usecols='F:G',
                                header=3)
df_participants.dropna(inplace=True)
```

What am I doing wrong that I can't find the file? The file is in the same folder as the script itself

Comment: Well the most obvious one would be to check if the file is there and if the casing matches. Make sure its `xlsx` and not `xls` etc.

Comment: @BijayRegmi yes, its Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)

Comment: the file name starts with capital letter **Survey.xlsx** check the file in your working dir to to confirm that. Else it might be a spelling mistake.